# FilePersistence class in GXT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gxt

I am trying to make a gxt application by following this link [enter link description here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/235-what-is-ext-gwt-20-2.html)

There they mentioned that add an instance of FilePersistence is it a builtin class?? if so please help me find that

I just added "javax.persistence" to my class path it doesnot worked.
Am using

Jdk 1.6

Eclipse 3.6

They mentioned That `The Persistence interface and a FilePersistence implementation of that interface can be found in the example code.`  Help me to find that

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `FilePersistence` class first:

```
private final Persistence persistence = new FilePersistence();
```

And when you wish to save your data, just do the following

```
persistence.saveFeedList(feeds.keySet());
```

This assumes you have correctly retrieved the feeds you want to save and properly stored them in a hashmap as stated in the [example](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/235-what-is-ext-gwt-20-2.html).

Comment: Thank you .... But they are using their own class how we know about that. They told that this class can found in Example help me to find that or tell me the about the FilePersistance class

Comment: also This persistance class is not belongs to javax.persistance

Answer (score 0):

Download the example code for PACKT Publishing's website.  Go [here](http://www.packtpub.com/support), use the dropdown to select "Ext GWT 2.0: Beginner's Guide" and go through the registration process to get access to the downloads.  The example code will contain the files you are looking for.